# What paper introduced max norm regularization (as used in neural network training)?

Tags: neural-networks, normalization, regularization, history

Max norm regularization consists in clipping each neuron's weight vector after each training step to ensure that its norm never exceeds some threshold.

I am looking for the original paper that described this technique. Using scholar.google.com, I found a couple of papers that people seem point to in papers about max norm, but they don't seem to correspond to the technique described above. They're about matrix factorization (and way out of my league):

- [Maximum-Margin Matrix Factorization](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/2655-maximum-margin-matrix-factorization.pdf), 2004, N. Srebro et al.
- [Practical Large-Scale Optimization for Max-Norm Regularization](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~nati/Publications/MaxNormNIPS2010.pdf), 2010, J. Lee et al.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This paper](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/srivastava14a/srivastava14a.pdf) specifically discusses max-norm with SGD. It references Srebro and Shraibman (2005), which makes me think that it/your implementation does in fact correspond to the technique you described.

> Max-norm regularization has been previously used in the context of collaborative filtering (Srebro and Shraibman, 2005). It typically improves the performance of stochastic gradient descent training of deep neural nets, even when no dropout is used.